# Opening Qt c++ project

Tags: c++, qt

I got a c++ gui project, but I only have .exe and .dll files. Is it possible to use Qt to modify this project? I suppose I'll need to get the .cpp and .h files in order to modify the project. Am I right? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need source files, i.e., .cpp and .h files to modify the project. You cannot directly modify executables or DLLs using Qt.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use Qt to modify this project?

Qt is a GUI framework, or C++ GUI library, not an IDE or editor. You can't **use** Qt to **modify** something.

You can do the following things with any IDE or editor:

1. modify the project configuration file `.pro` to change project
   settings.
2. modify the use interface file `.ui`(with Qt designer for
   convenience) to change UI.
3. modify the source file `.cpp .h` to change the logic of your
   program.
4. with only `.exe` and `.dll`, you can add source file with code
   directly accessing `.dll` with Windows API.